# After BIOS updating from LENOVO support site my laptop T520 beeps 1-3-3-1

Tags: bios, updates

I recently updated my Lenovo T520 BIOS via Lenovos support site. Just after the update the laptop doesn't work any more. When the power button pressed it beeps short: 1-3-3-1. I have disconnected BIOS' battery, tried to change to another working RAM but nothing changes. 
I hope you can help me.
Best regards
Thien

Comment: According to the Lenovo documentation, `1-3-3-1`, indicates a memory error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Will it even start in BIOS?  Reset BIOS Defaults if it does.
2. If no, did you get the correct file to update?  Was the laptop plugged into AC during the update?
3. You may at this point need to call Lenovo Support.

We have lots of Lenovo machines at clients and BIOS updates go correctly all the time. My machines here are Lenovo and I update BIOS on them.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply:)
1. The laptop worked normaly befor the updating. After the updating the machine restarted for the first time and it got the problem. I tried to disconnect the fan, the CMOS battery and waited to next day, the WLAN card and so on but nothing helps.
2. I connected the laptop to the Lenovo support website when I updated, the Website  detected correctly my laptops model and suggested the BIOS US 7/8 vrs.1.49 because it classified my old BIOS to 'Critical'. The updating process underwent correctly as it must be also the laptop was plugged into AC power supply.

Comment: The updating ended also correctly and automatically restarted the laptop. So I am very disappointed with Suport's suggestion. I had updated BIOS many times before and this time is the first time I get problem.
3. My Laptop is out of guaranty.
Best regards. Thien

Comment: There may be another hardware issue with the laptop that is preventing the BIOS from updating

Comment: Some mystery happened here is every hardware worked well just before  the updating! :(.

Comment: So is BIOS updating now?

Comment: I think so because after the updating process Finished the laptop restarted as normal procedure but it couldn't: The screen is black, the 1-3-3-1sequence  beeps once and nothing happen more after that until I turn it off. I think it got some wrong BIOS. The 1-3-3-1 sequence beeps tells that there is a problem with the RAM. I have another laptop of the same model then I tried to insert  the RAM of the  problematic laptop  into the working laptop. It could run without any problem.

Comment: I agree that I think you got an incorrect BIOS file. Try Lenovo Support one more time for the correct BIOS download